# multiple switcher works incorrect CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an on/off switch, but it works incorrectly. I have a few rows with the switch. It's auto generated so that when I click every row except the first it switches 1 row.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
                    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
```

and css:

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative;
    width: 88px;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.onoffswitch .onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block;
    width: 200%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch .onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    width: 50%; 
    height: 33px;
    padding: 0; 
    line-height: 33px;
    color: white; 
    font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "Yes";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: blue; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "No";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #ccc; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; 
    width: 30px; 
    margin: 5px 0;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 53px;
    border: 2px solid #D6D6D6; border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch > .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label > .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch > .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label >.onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

I try to do it with CSS only, without JS(JQuery, etc...)

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: It's working. https://jsfiddle.net/92op8eu7/1/ What is the issue?

Comment: @ketan, I make a table, so cell with swither generate automatically, when I switch, 2, 3 etc... every time switches only 1-st

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfv76omw/

You should set an unique `id` and `name` attribute for the elements

`name="onoffswitch"` `id="myonoffswitch"` and `for="myonoffswitch"` must be unique.

I simply added an incremental number like

`name="onoffswitch1"` `id="myonoffswitch1"` and `for="myonoffswitch1"`
`name="onoffswitch2"` `id="myonoffswitch2"` and `for="myonoffswitch2"`
`name="onoffswitch3"` `id="myonoffswitch3"` and `for="myonoffswitch3"`